# System.limitException : Too many SOQL queries 101

Tags: apex, trigger

```
 public static void questionaire(List<ID> workshop_ids) {
    String template_name = 'Questionaire';
    Id template_id = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate Where Name = :template_name limit 1].Id;
    Id owa_email_id;
    // Use Organization Wide Address  
    for(OrgWideEmailAddress owa : [select id, Address, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress]) {
        if(owa.DisplayName.contains('Service')) {
            owa_email_id = owa.id;
        } 
    } 
    List<Workshop__c> workshops_to_update = new List<Workshop__c>();
    Map<Id,List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>> attachment_map = createAttachmentMap(workshop_ids);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Workshop_Invitation__c> ws_invitations = [select Id, Contact__c, Account__r.Type,
                                                   Contact__r.Pension_Customer_Status__c, Workshop__r.Status__c, 
                                                   Workshop__r.Id, Workshop__r.Room__c, Workshop__r.City__c, Workshop__r.Country__c, 
                                                   Workshop__r.Postcode__c, Workshop__r.Street__c, Workshop__r.Start_Date__c, Workshop__r.End_Date__c, 
                                                   Status__c from Workshop_Invitation__c 
                                                   where (Status__c = 'Invited_to_workshop' or Status__c = 'Created') and Contact__c != null and 
                                                   Workshop__c in :workshop_ids];
    System.debug('B');
    for (Workshop_Invitation__c ws_invitation: ws_invitations) {
        if(ws_invitation.Account__r.Type != 'OnlineCustomer'){
        System.debug('SendOutsForWorkshop + ws_invitation.Account__r.Type :: ' + ws_invitation.Account__r.Type);
        mails.add(createEmail(ws_invitation, ws_invitation.Id, owa_email_id, template_id, attachment_map.get(ws_invitation.Workshop__c)));
        ws_invitation.Status__c = 'Questionaire_sent';
        if (!workshops_to_update.contains(ws_invitation.Workshop__r)) {
            System.debug('C');
            Workshop__c workshop = ws_invitation.Workshop__r;
            workshop.Status__c = 'Questionaire_sent';
            workshops_to_update.add(workshop);
        }
        }
    }
    if (mails.size()>0) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
    update ws_invitations;
    update workshops_to_update;
}
```

I do not have any SOQL in my for loops but I still get this error. Can anyone help me solve this issue? What am I missing here?

Comment: The limit might not happen from your specific function. At the end you update ws_invitations and workshop_to_update, those update might invoke trigger/process builder which does additional logic each might have additional queries and all together result in this limit. You should look at the debug log and see exactly what happen in the process and where it is failing

Comment: Also, add System.debug(Limit.getQueries()) in few places within your code (esp, before and after the last 2 update statements) to see where you are actually hitting the limit. This may make your debugging easier.

Comment: does your `createEmail()` method contain any queries? If so, then you do have a query in a loop (since `createEmail()` is called inside of a loop). Also keep in mind that the 100 query limit is cumulative for the entire transaction.

Comment: I found the problem in the other logic after this trigger executes and I fixed the SOQL. Thanks everybody